# How force apache to use Absolute addressing?

Tags: apache, web-hosting

I have a site in my local machine which has some subdirectory for its pages, for example, this is my directory plan:

```
Root
|__default.html
|_About
|   |_default.html
|_Product
    |_p1.html
    |_p2.html
```

in my menu in all pages I have this code:

```
<li>
   <ul><a href="about/default.html">about</ul>
   <li>
      <ul><a href="product/p1.html">p1</ul>
      <ul><a href="Product/p2.html">p2</ul>
   </li>
</li>
```

when I am in my home page all things work properly but when I go to my subdirectories link shown with current subdirectory name. sample: when I am in about page my product links are shown as **about/product/p1.html** and  **about/product/p1.html** but they must be without about section.

I change my home page name whit default config of apache:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/newrock>
        DirectoryIndex default.htm
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: What code builds your menu links?  If they were hardcoded, this would not happen.  So you have some code server side that does that.  It should always refer to the top directory, and not use the current directory.  I also wonder if you really need `MultiViews`, very few actually do...

Comment: No these code are hard coded and there is no server side code

Comment: Say you setup a link to product1: `<a href="Product/p1.html">`.  Put that exact same link definition in ALL the pages.  `/default.html`, `/about/default.html`, ...  No mater what file you access later, the link will always point to "Product/p1.html", since that is what you put in your code.  It the linked changed, then something (i.e. server side code) is changing your HTML pages content.  Find that, and you have your solution.  No static html file is changed "magically" :-)